# Repository not found git mac terminal

Tags: github, terminal, repository, mac

No Mac depois que utiliza-se pela primeira vez os dados de usuário e senha do github no terminal esses dados ficam pré-configurados para uso futuro. Se tento clonar ou fazer o push com outro usuário dá erro. Geralmente diz que o repositório não foi encontrado ou não existe. Já tentei várias coisas. Desde colocar o usuario na url de clonar até usar o git config com o outro usuário e nada adiantou. Poderiam por favor me dar uma ajuda com isso?

Comment: Está fazendo o clone/push via SSH ou HTTPS? Se for SSH você precisa configurar sua chave publica no seu repositório.

Comment: Tentei das duas formas (ssh/https) e nenhuma funcionou, mas não fiz a configuração da chave como relatou. Qual seria o procedimento para fazer isso?

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account